# turning off the squiggly lines for code

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-2003, word-2003

How do I turn off the red and green lines that appear under the grammer and spelling errors??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a new style for code - set an appropriate font and line spacing etc and turn off spell checking for the style. Apply this style to all your code examples.

Comment: +1. This is a good answer, especially if you do documentation for a living.

Comment: Yup, this is what I do.  I usually define two styles: "Inline Code" would be formatted as Courier New 9pt (or your preference) and spell checking disabled, and then a "Block Code" that adds indentation useful for code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to just right-click on the word and choose Ignore (Once or All). You can also go into Options under spell check and turn this off

Comment: I guess you have with lots of time on your hands!

Comment: @mdma: That's a pretty dumb remark. If you're doing this once or twice only, it's wasteful to set up a new style. If you're doing this as a living, add a new style. Even better, create a custom dictionary.